# How are these modern physics figures made?

Tags: soft-question, software

I am curious to know how the figures in these popular introductory physics textbooks are made. As examples of what I mean, see the posted figures and my comments, all from various editions of Serway and Jewett (I think).

[image: Figure1]

Look at all of these color gradients throughout the metals, and the imitations of lighting on the spheres. Notice the relatively realistic nature of the force scale and pullies.

[image: Figure2]

Notice here that we have proper, LaTeX-like font on the vectors.

[image: Figure3]
<sub>(source: [jvarrian at facstaff.cbu.edu](http://facstaff.cbu.edu/%7Ejvarrian/252/reactor.jpg))</sub>

Wow. So many complex shapes, good water drawings, and the ability to annotate the drawing freely.

[image: Figure4]

Lastly, we see more extremely complicated, realistic objects, like the ship and the mountain. But this isn't just pictures, it's clear that the software used has a very precise coordinate system in it, as evidenced by the kinematics drawings overlaid.

I am aware of the other posts on SE recommending drawing softwares such as LaTeX, TiKZ, pstricks, aymptote, matlab, mathematica, etc. But I highly doubt these figures were produced in any of these. My suspicion is that the publishers have some specialized software for this task. So what is that software? Does anyone know?

And a side question, when a textbook gets as popular as Serway & Jewett, do the authors still make the figures? Or do the publishers take over that job once the book exceeds some amount of popularity?

Thank You!

Update:
I emailed and got a response from Professor Randall Knight, author of Physics for Scientists and Engineers: A Strategic Approach. He told me that the publisher, Pearson, makes his final drawings, and that they use illustrator.

Another data point is that Michael Stone made his own figures for his book Mathematics for Physics: A Guided Tour for Graduate Students published by Cambridge Press. And he used a less known software whose name I can't recall.

I also posted this question on the graphic design SE and got a useful answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71327/how-are-these-modern-physics-figures-made

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's devoid of physics.

Comment: Where should it be posted, then? I believe the "soft-question" tag is for this sort of question, is it not?

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa [the graphicdesign stackexchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) might work better

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa the question is not bad (one can see that effort has been put into it), it's just that it doesn't really belong in here... (BTW: for these kind of illustrations I usually go with [Illustrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator))

Comment: I was hoping someone in the physics community was familiar with the textbook publication process, and may provide an answer... If I post it in the graphicdesign SE (not a bad idea) I wonder if the question would be read by someone familiar with textbook creation, in particular... I figure there would at least be more interest in this community.

Comment: You have a better chance of finding someone familiar with graphic design packages in Graphic Design SE than in Physics SE.  Not many of us here have published our own textbooks.  Even if we have, a professional graphic designer has probably done the illustrations for us.  It isn't a question of interest, it is a question of expertise.  Our expertise is academic physics, not graphic design packages.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the publisher?  Better still, look for the credits for illustrations in the Acknowledgements.

Comment: You can make these kinds of drawings with almost any desktop drawing software. I would go a little beyond the capabilities of Powerpoint, but other than that there is nothing special here.

Comment: @sammygerbil I've talked to a couple of professors that published graduate level texts at UI-Urbana-Champaign, and they have said that they made their own figures. I was surprised to find that out... Contacting the publisher is something I hadn't thought of, good idea.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm sure many softwares CAN draw it. I'm more interested in knowing what the pros actually use; those softwares are likely to be the most efficient for the task. When one is making dozens of figures, efficiency is key...

Comment: The most efficient software is usually the software you know best. All tools have strengths and weaknesses and it's the combination of the user and the tool that creates the result. Nobody makes drawing tools just for science illustrations and high quality science illustrations have existed for centuries. One could even argue that some of the highest quality science illustrations were made with pens and quills and brushes. Collectors of such works will certainly pay a lot more money for a 19th or 18th century naturalist drawing than for any of these.

Comment: In practice, every graphic designer I know uses Adobe Illustrator.  The figures shown in the question, with a few simple gradients and textures would be very easy in all graphic design software.  If you want to try this yourself, Inkscape is very easy to use and is free, and could do all of the illustrations you show without a lot of effort.  This question is off-topic for this forum, but illustrations are also a useful technique for communication of science, and as such, it's not a waste of time for scientists to learn a bit about how to do make nice ones.

Comment: @tom10 I see... From what you know, would incorporating LaTeX be possible in either Inkscape or Illustrator?

Comment: When I've needed to do this, I've made a raster image from Latex and imported it into the figure, but this isn't ideal.  Instead, all vector graphics software use Bezier curves well, and I'm sure Latex will have a way to output equations in that format, and that would be the way to go, but I haven't done it.  It would also be possible to make a plugin to, say, edit an equation within vector graphics software, but I don't know of such a thing.  (Also, Latex wouldn't be required for the simple subscripts, etc shown above, but real equations could benefit from it.)

Comment: GeoGebra, free and more important :  incorporates LaTeX.   **(1)**: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256163/vertical-circular-motion-how-can-tension-be-negative/256208#256208 **(2)**:http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255990/how-do-we-define-what-is-external-force-or-internal-force-in-the-context-of/255996#255996 **(3)** : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253794/refraction-of-light-rays/254205#254205  **(4)** : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194141/a-confusion-regarding-an-example-in-the-feynman-lectures

Comment: My personal experience is that the process goes like this:  The author provides rough sketches of the figures along with written descriptions of what's important (e.g. "Point A must be directly above Point B".)  These are submitted to the publisher, where an idiot in the art department rewrites the descriptions, changing their meanings substantially.  These new descriptions are then sent to a freelance artist who carefully follows the new instructions, producing figures that bear no resemblance to the authors' intentions.  The author objects,  and the entire process is repeated 17 times (CTD)

Comment: (CTD) until the publisher finally agrees to allow the author to communicate directly with the artist, at which point a brief telephone conversation ensues and perfectly rendered art is delievered in short order.

Comment: lol @WillO. Though I assume this practice varies from publisher to publisher, and also varies with the popularity of the textbook? As the book gets more popular, the publisher plays a more direct role? I doubt a publisher would invest as much effort in a relatively esoteric graduate text as they would in a widely used, introductory physics text... One data point, Michael Stone made all of the diagrams for his Mathematical Methods book himself. It is published by the reputable Cambridge Press.

Comment: @MaanDoabeDa : I used XFig for my math physics book. It's open source, runs under Xwindowsn but a bit dated now. Also CUP messed up the figures, and I had to redo them.